# Protractor and IE11 navigation issue

Tags: angularjs, selenium, angular-ui-bootstrap, protractor, protractor-net

I am using [Protractor.Net](https://github.com/bbaia/protractor-net) and having a weird issue with IE. I believe the issue has something to do with the site bootstrapping but not knowledgeable enough to figure it out. However same code works fine on `Chrome` and `Firefox`.

There are two different tests I am executing on same page. My application is `non-angular` and `angualr` hybrid. After navigating to the Angular page first test executes without any issue. For testing need I navigate to the same `url` again and when I am trying to do that it's breaking.The attachments are also available at [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poZm3.png)
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8X6w.png)
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BzNT.png)
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX12V.png)

```
 //Navigate and binds the page

 public TestPage TestPage()
 {
     string url = BaseUrl + "/n/Test/TestPage#/";

     //need to handle asyn script call timeout
     Driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

     NgWebDriver ngDriver = new NgWebDriver(Driver, "[ng-app='Test']");
     ngDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);

     return new TestPage(ngDriver);
 }



// Resume Angular bootstrap this is in URL setter and  fails here on second iteration
this.jsExecutor.ExecuteScript(ClientSideScripts.ResumeAngularBootstrap,
String.Join(",", this.mockModules.Select(m => m.Name).ToArray()));
```

Comment: Well, I didn't downvote but it's obvious why that person did: Code should _never_ be added as an image (not as readable, can't be copied or indexed, high-resolution link might go dead). The same applies to your answer. Replace all images with actual code.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Replaced as you suggested

Comment: "Rewarded" with an upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a bug in the project. Setting the following line before in `URL` property setter solves the issue !

```
this.driver.Url = "about:blank";

 get
{
    this.WaitForAngular();
    IHasCapabilities hcDriver = this.driver as IHasCapabilities;
    if (hcDriver != null && hcDriver.Capabilities.BrowserName == "internet explorer")
    {
        // 'this.driver.Url' does not work on IE
       //this.driver.Url = "about:blank"; //this is bug fix
        return this.jsExecutor.ExecuteScript(ClientSideScripts.GetLocationAbsUrl, this.rootElement) as string;
    }
    else
    {
        return this.driver.Url;
    }
}
```